# About multiple conversations and/or queues

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, service, service-broker

I'm wondering about the exact definition of a conversation and MS docs and tutorials are not quite on point with this.

First... is there a difference between a dialog and a conversation ?

Assuming a queue should only contain identical messages or equivalent messages (I.E. message types being handled by an activated procedures in a way similar to a CASE WHEN / SWITCH scenario)

- Does each conversation revolve around a unique queue?
- If a procedure A sends a message to a queue activating a procedure B which handle the message then emits an answer, can procedure A wait for the answer or should I use a procedure C? Am I right to assume that I must create two queues operating on the same contract? But how many services? In that scenario how and where would I use END CONVERSATION?
- If a procedure A sends a message to a queue activating a procedure B which handle the message then emits another/several messages(s) for another/some other procedure(s) C, are all those queues/services / etc. on the same conversation? The same conversation group? (what would I do after the GET CONVERSATION GROUP to ensure my conversations are in the same group?) Does that imply passing the same conversation handle when issuing BEGIN TRANSACTION / BEGIN DIALOG or using

  [ WITH
  [  { RELATED_CONVERSATION = related_conversation_handle
  | RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP = related_conversation_group_id } ]

? And... last but not least, If I'm using multiple messages to parallel/fork calls to C with different parameters, in which case would I want to start totally different conversations/conversations groups doing the same thing or is it always better to have a unique "narration"

- Oh... another thing... is there a best practice to use several messages to call some treatments then wait for every one of them to finish before starting another one? Is there a way in which each procedure would receive a message, send an answer, and then the procedure activated by the answers could check/count the previous messages in its queue and go on only if they are all there? Would that need to check the conversation id (or conversation group id) to be sure those messages are all emitted by the same group of answers?

  I hope that's not too much confusing but MS tutorials are... well... a bit simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a dialog is the same as a conversation as far as I can tell. Two names for the same thing.

Queues can contain many different message types. It's up to the the thing processing the messages (whether that's an internally activated stored procedure or an external application) to discriminate on the type and do the "right thing" with it. A service can have only one queue, but a queue can have many services (though I haven't actually seen that in practice). A service defines what message types is can both accept and produce through the service contract.

In regards to your question about whether you want a queue processor to respond on the same conversation or start a new one is completely up to you. My suggestion would be to respond on the same conversation unless you know that you have a good reason not to. As to how to use the same conversation, you can get the conversation handle when you issue the `receive` statement. Use that as the conversation handle when you issue the subsequent `send` with your reply.

The way I think about conversation groups is you may need to talk to different services in regards to the same thing. Here's a contrived example:

Let's say that I have a new hire process. It has the following steps:

- Create a login
- Create an entry in the payroll system
- Register them with your insurance provider

They're all logically for the same event though (i.e. "I hired a new employee"). So, you could bundle all of the conversations in one conversation group and keep track of the individual conversations separately. Something like this:

```
declare @handle uniqueidentifier, @group uniqueidentifier = NEWID(), 
@message XML = '<employee name="Ben Thul" />';

BEGIN TRAN
    begin dialog @handle
        from service [EmployeeService]
        to service 'LoginService'
        on contract [LoginContract]
        with related_conversation_group = @group;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION (@handle)
        MESSAGE TYPE [NewLoginRequest]
        (@message);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OpenRequests]
    (
        [GroupIdentifier],
        [ConversationIdentifier],
        [ServiceName],
        [Status],
        [date_modified]
    )
    VALUES
        (@group, @handle, 'LoginService', 'RequestSent', GETUTCDATE());

    BEGIN DIALOG @handle
        FROM SERVICE [EmployeeService]
        TO SERVICE 'PayrollService'
        ON CONTRACT [PayrollContract]
        WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP = @group;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION (@handle)
        MESSAGE TYPE [NewPayrollRequest]
        (@message);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OpenRequests]
    (
        [GroupIdentifier],
        [ConversationIdentifier],
        [ServiceName],
        [Status],
        [date_modified]
    )
    VALUES
        (@group, @handle, 'PayrollService', 'RequestSent', GETUTCDATE());

    BEGIN DIALOG @handle
        FROM SERVICE [EmployeeService]
        TO SERVICE 'InsuranceService'
        ON CONTRACT [InsuranceContract]
        WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP = @group;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION (@handle)
        MESSAGE TYPE [NewInsuranceRequest]
        (@message);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OpenRequests]
    (
        [GroupIdentifier],
        [ConversationIdentifier],
        [ServiceName],
        [Status],
        [date_modified]
    )
    VALUES
        (@group, @handle, 'InsuranceService', 'RequestSent', GETUTCDATE());
COMMIT
```

Now, you have a way to track each of those requests separately *and* a way to tie them all to the same logical operation. As each service processes the message, it will respond back with either a success, failure, or "I need something else" message. At which point you can update the `OpenRequests` table with the current status.

Service broker can be overwhelming. My advice for you is to think about what messages need to be passed from where *to* where and start designing services, message types, contracts, etc around that. It's unlikely that you're going to use all of the functionality that SB has to offer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, am I rightfully understanding that your answer to my last problem (initiating processes, then gathering answers to know when everything is done and start a final one) would rather be using a tracking table than count/analyse related answers in the queue within the activated procedure ?

Comment: I think so, yes. In my contrived example, you know that there are three actual operations that stem from the logical operation of hiring a new employee. Each of those actual operations might be a simple "send one message and receive a reply" or a complex back-and-forth. You have the flexibility to define the message flow based on how simple or complex the interaction you're modeling is.

Comment: I'm getting errors 9610...  

The service '<initiator service from new conversation>' in the FROM SERVICE clause must match the service '<target service from first conversation>' referenced by %s = '%.*ls'.

Does that mean that conversations groups must reference services based on the same contracts ?

Comment: If need to know a little more about what you tried, but it looks like you tried to send to two different services on the same conversation handle. I can verify later, but my understanding is that you can place what would be otherwise unrelated conversations.